# Adding to a string in javascript with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I have a string in Javascript and i want to add something to it when a checkbox is checked and the submit button is activated.

What i have is this:

```
var strDimensions = ["Sex","Age"]; 

$("input[id='Class']:checked").each(function() {
            strDimensions += "Class"; 
    }       
);

var chart = d3.parsets().dimensions(strDimensions);
```

The only thing thats not working is adding up `Class` to the string.

i want strDimensions to be this when the checkbox is checked:

```
strDimensions = ["Sex","Age","Class"];
```

Comment: You are trying to concatenate an array and a string, which looks weird.

Comment: what are you trying to add ?..... a sub string to each array element or adding another element to array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you mean `Array.push`?

```
strDimensions.push("Class");
```